# html5 is it possible to LIVE stream a .webm as it's being generated

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, video-player

I'm using openvidu https://openvidu.io/ with the record function.

This record feature, generates live a .webm

when I place it in a video tag

```
<video width="90%" height="669" controls id="webmlive" preload="metadata" >
      <source src="..../recordings/sessionName/id121212.webm" type="video/webm" >
    </video>
```

and adding this

```
<script>
        
        webmlive = document.getElementById("webmlive");
        
        webmlive.addEventListener("loadedmetadata" , function() {
            console.log("vStreamDuration "+webmlive.duration);
        }, false);
        
    </script>
```

the log says "vStreamDuration Infinity"

by default it's starting at 0 and plays, but unable to scroll the video, only pause work...

how can I start the play at the latest point and let user decide to scroll to the beginning...

Comment: You should use a format built for live streaming. like HLS or DASH

Comment: @szatmary I know about HLS and DASH, but the built-in feature in openvidu is generating a .webm, I'm able to control the timeline playback with javascript like `.currentTime=0` or any value, the video will play at the specified time... but I need a way to "reload" the video metadata on the fly... I'M sure there is a way out there.... but hidden...

Comment: It's possible, but you're going to have to do a lot of implementation work yourself with Media Source Extensions.

Answer (score 0):

I found something like this

the argument -re -framerate forces to encode at input framerate, if not, it stops in the middle of the stream...

```
ffmpeg -re -framerate 29.97 -i "https://example.com/recordings/weex-7/str_CAM_HGgs_con_XZQOm4Zem0.webm" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -ac 1 -strict -2 -crf 18 -profile:v baseline -maxrate 1000k -bufsize 1835k -pix_fmt yuv420p -flags -global_header -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 6 -hls_wrap 10 -start_number 1 'index.m3u8'
```